# Custom react hook initial value return null, how prevent that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have custom react hook but it always return null for the first render and only second time is needed value

```
const useGetUrlParams = (params) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (params === null) {
            return '';
        }

        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const res = urlParams.get(params);
        setData(res);
       
    }, [params]);

    return [data];
    
};
```

how is that possible to prevent and return the correct value only once from the first attempt?

I have no idea what to  do with that.

Answer (score 0):

First, we must ask where the data that we enter into the state UI is coming from. How long will it take to get them? From these, we will know when data will come in.

Your example can be implemented as follows:

```
const useGetUrlParams = (params) => {
    const getData = (params) => {
       if (params === null) {
            return '';
        }

        const queryString = window.location.search;
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
        const res = urlParams.get(params);

        return res;
    }
    const [data, setData] = useState(getData(params));

    useEffect(() => {
       const data = getData(params);
       setData(data);
    }, [params]);

    return [data];
    
};
```

The value of the state is entirely dependent on how and when the other parameters can adapt to it. In example: If in the first render, params is valid, you can get expected state's value else you must be get unexpected state's value, no solution in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Extract the code to a function and use it for the `useState` as well.

You can use the [lazy initial state](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state) approach to avoid re-running an expensive computation each time your hook is run, and also use a flag (*`useRef`*) to not run the same code in the `useEffect` on the first execution.

```js
function getParams(params) {
  if (params === null) {
    return '';
  }
  const queryString = window.location.search;
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
  const res = urlParams.get(params);
  return res;
}

const useGetUrlParams = (params) => {
// use the isFirstRun trick
// to avoid calling re-running the 
// getParams and setting the state in the
// useEffect on the first run (since we already
// calculate it when initialising the useState)
  const isFirstRun = useRef(true);
 // use the lazy initial state setting
  const [data, setData] = useState(() => getParams(params));

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isFirstRun.current) {
      isFirstRun.current = false;

    } else {
      setData(getParams(params));
    }
  }, [params]);

  return [data];

};
```